# Loading a large list in Blazor

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to load a list of students at moment I have a signalr connection and the request gets all students. I'd like to scroll down the list and it would load a 100 students at a time?

```
<ul>
            @if (Students != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var student in Students)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <div class="treeview__item__header">
                                @plan.Name
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
         </ul>


        @code
        {   
         private List<StudentsData> Students { get; set; } 

         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
         {
             Students = await StudentsConnection.GetStudents();
         }   
        }
```

Comment: [Linq Skip Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: An `<ul>` doesn't support scrolling. Maybe start with a DataGrid component.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this example with success:

https://github.com/amuste/DnetVirtualScrolling

in alternative, as Alexander stated, a simple pager calculated on the number of rows to show and  seems to be the best "pure blazor" solution

Edit: **Looks like Virtualize could be perfect for this use:**

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/asp-net-core-blazor-component-virtualization-in-net-5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should consider solution on store procedure level with
 Select top 100 where and have a parameter @next
With witch you could control from app with button or event when you scroll down to the end of list

Answer (score 0):

you can use pagination and implement a pager component. Look at these two articles, they may help you: [Pager component](https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-pager-component/) and part of [Pager component 2](https://www.blogofpi.com/sorting-and-paging-in-blazor-using-ef-core/)